# iPad Popover -[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController: must not be called with `nil`

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I'm still working my way around the iOS SDK and I have another probably easy one for you.
I'm getting the following error when attempting to present a popover:

> CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: -[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController: must not be called with `nil`.

I thought I had put in code to deal with this, although apparently not. Anyway, code is below. Any thoughts on this would be great. Cheers!

```
if(popoverController == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"is nil");
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverDownload];
}
popoverController.delegate = self;
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0,400,200) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

**UPDATE**

I guess I'm not initialising popoverDownload correctly/at all.
In my .h file

```
PopoverDownloadViewController *popoverDownload;
@property (nonatomic,retain) PopoverDownloadViewController *popoverDownload;
```

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER**

And it was as easy as...

```
PopoverDownloadViewController *popoverDownload = [[PopoverDownloadViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: How do you initialize `popoverDownload`? Apparently this is nil...

Comment: I have just updated the question with a bit more info. Though I'm guessing i'm not initialising popoverDownload correctly.

Comment: Okay, so that's the declaration, but where do you actually _create_ it?

Comment: Ah, duh! You are right... I have done it now. Shall update the code to show. I guess that's what I get for being not very well and not having drank any coffee yet today! Cheers for the hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this answer closed. I needed to initialise the popover using the following code...

```
PopoverDownloadViewController *popoverDownload = [[PopoverDownloadViewController alloc] init];
```

Thanks to omz for the hints in the right direction.